# How to Prevent users to see admin views

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am currently having a techincal issue. I've configured Multi Auth in my application and everything is fine. There are some views on my application where I'm giving access to only admins. And I'm achieving this by using

```
@if(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
    // my restricted navigation links / routes.
@endif
```

But the problem is that whenever the admin is online the condition sets to true and the links are visible to all the users with other guards. Please help me how can I prevent other users to see those links even if the admin is logged in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent unauthorized users to access admin pages in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097967/prevent-unauthorized-users-to-access-admin-pages-in-laravel-5)

Comment: No... I don't think so...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your app is multi auth, I assume you have roles (and possibly permissions) set up.

The laravel-permission package by Spatie contains a Blade directive `@role('<insert intended role>')` & `@endrole`. Which I use in my own app to prevent normal users to see content that is intended for specific roles.

For example:

> `@role('admin')`
>
> `<a href="/admin/users/1/edit">Edit</a>;`
>
> `@endrole`

A user with the admin role can see this link, others can't.

Adding to this, you can also enable middleware on this route:

> `Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->prefix('admin')->group(function (Router $router) {
>   $router->get('/users/{user}', 'AdminUserController@edit')
>   });`

Comment: I've already done it with another logic... But seems like , this is another way to tackle the problem, 
So , thanks for another suggestion as well.